# Rest API to a Magento 2 Site

Tags: magento2

Is there a way to make a REST API call to a website built in Magento 2? The scenario is I have multiple site and the header of these sites are shared whether I go to website 1 or website 2. Now when I go to website 1 and select/add an item to the cart I would like this cart count to be available in the other websites. So I was thinking having an API call to a certain website then retrieve that value to be displayed.

But I'm not sure if this is the best approach or if there is available REST API resource I can use to retrieve information of a website data. Like if I'm in website 2 I would like to get the information of website 1 I would just send a REST request to retrieve this information.

Comment: Is that both website 1 and 2 are magento2?

Comment: @L.C.EchoChan No only website 1 is in Magento while Website 2 is in different PHP framework. Although there is also another website 3 which is made in magento 2 also

Comment: @MadzQuestioning It is definitely possible. Magento has a built in api. You can read more on it [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/rest_front.html).